WebApp is connected with firebase. Want to automate app using api's in cypress

Started by writing test cases to cover user interactions with web application.
Used Cypress's API commands such as cy.visit(), cy.get(), cy.type(), etc., to interact with elements on the web page.
Utilized Firebase API calls within mine Cypress tests to manipulate data and perform assertions.
Example: If application involves user authentication, write tests to verify login functionality using Firebase Authentication API.

Trying to add auth test in cypress
Here's sample code below.
    // Add data to Firebase Realtime Database
    cy.request('PUT', 'https://your-firebase-project.firebaseio.com/data.json', {
      key: 'value'
    }).then((response) => {
      expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
    });

Is there any other work around like we use rest API's for auth. Major issue is to use auth from firebase in cypress.

Did you try https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#firebase_id_tokens?

Yes tried that...

Since that is the documented way of authorizing Realtime Database access through the REST API, please edit your question to show what you tried and what error you got.
